# 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' not working

Tags: sort

We have a simple plugin to display a tree menu, which includes the parent page, plus the parent page's children (so, the siblings of the current page).

We're using the following `get_pages` code:

```
$pages = get_pages( [
   'child_of' => $parent,
   'sort_order' => 'ASC',
   'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
]);
```

However, the pages are listed in ascending order of date created (oldest first).

How do we make the pages be listed in the page order in the right sidebar of the edit page screen?

Answer (score 2):

When the `child_of` parameter is set, `get_pages()` will use [`get_page_children()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_children/) to get the child pages, and unfortunately, the `sort_column` will no longer be used, hence the final list will not be sorted by the specified custom sort column, so you'll need to use your own code for getting the list with the expected sort column (and order).

Here's an example which uses a custom function that's called recursively (until all child pages are retrieved) and then [`walk_page_tree()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_page_tree/) is used (instead of `wp_list_pages()` which has the same issue as `get_pages()`) to output the pages in a list (`li`) layout:

```php
// In the theme functions file:
function my_get_pages( $parent, $orderby = 'menu_order', $order = 'ASC' ) {
    $pages = get_pages( array(
        'parent'      => $parent,
        'sort_column' => $orderby,
        'sort_order'  => $order,
    ) );

    $children = array();
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $children[] = $page;

        // Retrieve grandchildren.
        $children2 = my_get_pages( $page->ID, $orderby, $order );
        if ( ! empty( $children2 ) ) {
            $children = array_merge( $children, $children2 );
        }
    }

    return $children;
}

// In your template:
$parent = 123; // parent post/Page ID

$pages = my_get_pages( $parent );

echo '<ul>' .
    walk_page_tree( $pages, 0, get_queried_object_id(), array() ) .
'</ul>';
```

Here's another example, similar to the above, but this one doesn't use `walk_page_tree()` — and you've got full control over the HTML:

```php
// In the theme functions file:
function my_wp_list_pages( $parent, $orderby = 'menu_order', $order = 'ASC' ) {
    $pages = get_pages( array(
        'parent'      => $parent,
        'sort_column' => $orderby,
        'sort_order'  => $order,
    ) );

    if ( empty( $pages ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Just change the HTML markup based on your liking..
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        printf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
            esc_url( get_permalink( $page ) ),
            get_the_title( $page ) );

        // Display grandchildren.
        my_wp_list_pages( $page->ID, $orderby, $order );
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

// In your template:
$parent = 123; // parent post/Page ID

my_wp_list_pages( $parent );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Sally. Is there a way to grab the `$parent` dynamically, as it is used on several pages?

Comment: Yes, there is, but as for the code, it depends on which parent you want. E.g. To get the oldest ancestor, you can use [`get_post_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/) and grab the last item in the returned value/array. Or maybe `get_post()->post_parent` to get the direct parent.

Comment: What about the most primary page, i.e. the one with parents of its own?

Comment: I don't really get that, and it's probably better if you asked that in another post..

Comment: Sorry Sally, I miswrote, I meant `What about the most primary page, i.e. the one with no parents of its own?`

Comment: And sorry @Steve, I completely forgot about this :( But today, I remembered it somehow.. :) So for Pages where the `post_parent` is `0`, then use the Page ID. E.g. `$post = get_post(); $parent = $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID; my_get_pages( $parent );`

Answer (score 0):

Both the [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) and [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) functions have a `sort_column` parameter where you can pass in `menu_order`. For example:

```
$output = wp_list_pages( [
    'include'       => $page_ids,
    'title_li'      => false,
    'echo'          => false,
    'sort_column'   => 'menu_order',
] );
```

Menu Order will be the "Order" field seen in the [Page Attributes Metabox](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/) or Page Attributes section of the Block Editor.

Comment: Looks like `get_pages` can accept a parameter `'sort_column' => 'menu_order'`

Answer (score 0):

Use usort to sort the resulting $pages array based on menu_order

```
usort($pages, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->menu_order - $b->menu_order;
});
```